# How to push action form with variable of select?

Tags: php, html, selection

I want to take value from select in html and push it into action url.
So when users select something value of action buyoption will be the value of the selection
I would prefer to do it with php if there is no option to do it with html.

This is my test buy it doesn't change the buyoption to selection variable..

please help

```html
 <form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/trades/trade/buyoption/selloption" method="POST">
    
                <div class="row">
                   
                    <div class="col-md-9 register-right" >
                    
                        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                                <h3 class="register-heading">TRADE</h3>
                                <div class="row register-form">
                                   
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
           <label for="buy"><b>YOU SEND:</b></label>
           
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            
                                            <select class="form-control" name="buyoption" id="buyoption">
                                                <option class="hidden"  selected disabled>Please select what you want to sell</option>
                                                <option value="btc">Bitcoin (BTC)</option>
                                                <option value="ltc">LITECOIN (LTC)</option>
                                                <option value="eur">NATIONAL BANK TRANSFER (EUR/USD/HRK)</option>
                                            </select>
                                                
                                            
                                            
                                        </div>
                                       
          <label for="buy"><b>YOU RECEIVE:</b></label>
            <div class="form-group">
                                            <select class="form-control" name="selloption" id="buyoption">
                                                <option class="hidden"  selected disabled>Please select what you want receive</option>
                                                <option value="btc">Bitcoin (BTC)</option>
                                                <option value="ltc">Litecoin (LTC)</option>
                                                <option value="eur">NATIONAL BANK TRANSFER (EUR/USD/HRK)</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

    
         
                                        <input type="submit" class="btnRegister"  value="Proceed"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: As your select element is inside `form`, you would be getting the value once the form is submitted.

Comment: When i put the start of form near the button sumbit i still getting (buyoption) as parametar and not the value of selection. What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [***There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

You can watch for `change` event of `select` element and on Change, manipulate the Action URL.

```js
let buyoption = document.getElementById('buyoption');
let selloption = document.getElementById('selloption');
let postForm = document.getElementById('postForm');
let action = postForm.getAttribute('action');
let replacerFn = function() {
  let temp = action;
  if (buyoption.value) {
    temp = temp.replace('buyoption', buyoption.value);
  }
  if (selloption.value) {
    temp = temp.replace('selloption', selloption.value);
  }

  postForm.setAttribute('action', temp);
  console.log('Action Attribute=> ', postForm.getAttribute('action'));
};
buyoption.addEventListener('change', function() {
  replacerFn();
});

selloption.addEventListener('change', function() {
  replacerFn();
});
```

```html
<form action="/trades/trade/buyoption/selloption" method="POST" id="postForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 register-right">
      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
          <h3 class="register-heading">TRADE</h3>
          <div class="row register-form">
            <div class="col-md-12"> <label for="buy"><b>YOU SEND:</b></label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="buyoption" id="buyoption">
                  <option class="hidden" selected disabled value="">Please select what you want to sell</option>
                  <option value="btc">Bitcoin (BTC)</option>
                  <option value="ltc">LITECOIN (LTC)</option>
                  <option value="eur">NATIONAL BANK TRANSFER (EUR/USD/HRK)</option>
                </select>
              </div><label for="buy"><b>YOU RECEIVE:</b></label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="selloption" id="selloption">
                  <option class="hidden" selected disabled value="">Please select what you want receive</option>
                  <option value="btc">Bitcoin (BTC)</option>
                  <option value="ltc">Litecoin (LTC)</option>
                  <option value="eur">NATIONAL BANK TRANSFER (EUR/USD/HRK)</option>
                </select>
              </div><input type="submit" class="btnRegister" value="Proceed" /> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes but when i put alert into script it works. when i use your code url is again with variable and not with right value action . what is wrong..

Comment: @ajmoprobatopet - I have made an edit. Could you check now?

Comment: Now only one variable comes, only buyoption or only selloption, one stays same

Comment: @ajmoprobatopet - ANother edit. This should solve your problem.